# reverse proxy to point proper server site based on ip

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

To start of please excuse any incorrect statements I make as I am an application developer and not to familiar with web-server configuration. I have 2 servers, both running Apache2. The first server just acts as a reverse proxy while the second server contains the actual webpages (there are different sites). I would like any request coming into the reverse proxy to be filtered by IP address ranges so that a specific IP range will be redirected to the proper site on my 2nd server. Essentially so IP's can only view the site they are allowed to view. My question is what would I have to configure on the reverse proxy server and on the 2nd webserver?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to use nginx as a reverse-proxy solution. Configure it to use upstream from your actual web-server with filtering. Configure your Apache on web-server to listen only on local network, or restrict  access to it by firewall.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I would prefer to have apache instead of switching to a new server as I have other things configured already which would be quite a hassel to switch.

Comment: Do you need help with configuring apache, limiting access by IP, or both ? You only need to configure the proxy server, not the other apache.

Comment: I have the reverse proxy already setup, I need to limit my different sites to certain ip's (e.g. so siteA can only be access by 192.168.1.0, siteB by only 192.168.2.0 etc)

Comment: This is a really dumb set up. And what you are proposing is even worse. The right way to fix the architecture is to run the same config on both machines, optionally with a reverse proxy on both machines.

Comment: See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html